# Android Heads Up notification not showing up

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am not able to find where i am getting wrong in building the Notification.

I want the notification to show at top when phone is active and
on lock screen when phone is in sleep.

Here is the code that i have tried. But not able to achive the result.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, openIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Normal")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
    .setVibrate(new long[] {1000})
    .setContentTitle(mainListItem.getTitle())
    .setContentText(mainListItem.getDetail())
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);


NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
```

Comment: What is the target sdk , compile and minimum sdk version you are using ?

Comment: Min sdk 14, target and compile sdk 26

Comment: That is the issue from version 26 you need to create a notification channel to show notification.  For more check the link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: I am running this app on android 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Comment: Try creating notification channels and see

Comment: Notification channels are only available at this moment for Android Oreo+ (version 8+). There is no compatibility with support libraries yet. We need to wait or apply other strategies

Answer (score 2):

**It's to late to answer...**

Seems like your code is work fine for me, but for some reasons, that stop your heads-up notification to showing up.

1. Please check if your current working app that's managed by some system settings like **Notification Center of your phone settings, if that's disabled your heads up notification, then your heads up notification not able to show** as the same in my phone the Notification Center set my app's notifications to Unchecked or Disabled the "Banners" (Display on the top of status bar) setting, it does by default when i installed any applications in my phone. then my heads up notification is not showing. **You need to checked or enabled it**.
2. If your app run in the android version 26 and later, you need to create a notification channel and please check your Notification Settings make sure that's not block your app's notifications.
   Hope it help.

Comment: Just to follow up, you only *need* to create a notification channel for your app if it *targets* version 26 or later, [per the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels): When you target Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or more notification channels. If your targetSdkVersion is set to 25 or lower, when your app runs on Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, it behaves the same as it would on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower.